Queued stuck in self-hosted GitHub Actions
The github runner is absolutely online & active.
The issue is that randomly job stucks in queued status. Sometimes Generate OpenAPI Specification step, sometimes Build Frontend APP, sometimes Deploy Backend APP etc.
This workflow was running perfectly for 1+ year until ~3 days ago.
It is queued and not changing while the runner is in Idle mode.
It gets stuck jumping from job to job.
I was used the following code but it does not effect anymore. (It should change node version to 16.14 but I have seen it worked in default server nodejs version as 20.15 and job failed because of the node version.)
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.14]

I changed this code into the following code: (It worked now more healthy now. It was not accepting cancel process. It was freezing for hours. But now I can cancel it and it accepts the cancel process now. Facing weird behaviours.)
      - name: Set up Node.js 16.14
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.14


GitHub Self-hosted runner terminal:


I run the workflow and if it stucks I cancel it and rerun it as the following process:
Stucked on third job:


Now stucked on second job: (I tried to remove one of Deploy job to minimize process to find the issue. But it absolutely behaviours weird.)


Freezed at the fourth job now:


Try v4 i.e. actions/setup-node@v4.

@Azeem problem still exists

Getting same issues as well but I only encounter it today while trying to build and deploy app. Using self hosted runner as well, when one job is finished, another job is not starting until I terminated my runner and start again... It was working fine for past ~1-2 years too :( Seems like the only way now is to just terminate the runner & restart again

I started a discussion here. We may find something out here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/146261

This issue was about GitHub service. They understand the issue and resolved they say.
You can follow this issue: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/3609#issuecomment-2520606406
